# How to schedule a cron job once a month, only on a weekday, somewhere between 5-7 days of the first month using CronR?

Tags: r, cron

I am using cronR to schedule a report that gets sent out once every month. The report shouldn't be sent out on a weekend and should be sent somewhere between the 5th to 7th day of the month, depending on if that day is a weekend. So let's say 5th is a Saturday, and 6th is a Sunday, so the report should get sent out on Monday. Or if 5th is a Sunday, then it should send on the 6th. I'm not sure how possible this is-I also am using cronR so the expressions the package uses seem to be less flexible than other Linix/Unix commands I am seeing as solutions here. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the conditioning you talk of here (dom 5-7) is not directly supported by the cron scheduler. While I'm not fluent in the `cronR` package itself (though I am comfortable with cron), I suspect the best path would be to *always* run it on each of days 5, 6, and 7, and have the R code check your day-of-week conditions.

For instance, try this function:

```r
weekday_run <- function(today = Sys.Date()) {
  dom <- format(today[1], format = "%d")
  dows <- format(today[1] - 0:1, format = "%u") # 1-7, Monday is 1
  (dom == "05" && !dows[1] %in% c("6","7")) ||
    (dom %in% c("06", "07") && dows[2] == "7")
}
```

Put a check for that in the beginning of your script. If it returns `TRUE`, then your conditions are met and the script should continue. If it returns `FALSE`, exit (do nothing, no harm done).

Demonstration:

```r
weekday_run(as.Date("2021-03-05")) # Fri <--
# [1] TRUE
weekday_run(as.Date("2021-03-06")) # Sat
# [1] FALSE
weekday_run(as.Date("2021-03-07")) # Sun
# [1] FALSE

weekday_run(as.Date("2021-04-05")) # Mon <--
# [1] TRUE
weekday_run(as.Date("2021-04-06")) # Tue
# [1] FALSE
weekday_run(as.Date("2021-04-07")) # Wed
# [1] FALSE

weekday_run(as.Date("2021-05-05")) # Wed <--
# [1] TRUE
weekday_run(as.Date("2021-05-06")) # Thu
# [1] FALSE
weekday_run(as.Date("2021-05-07")) # Fri
# [1] FALSE

weekday_run(as.Date("2021-06-05")) # Sat
# [1] FALSE
weekday_run(as.Date("2021-06-06")) # Sun
# [1] FALSE
weekday_run(as.Date("2021-06-07")) # Mon <--
# [1] TRUE
```

So at the top of your script, you'd have that function and call:

```r
if (!weekday_run()) quit(save="no", status=0)
```

I restated the default of `status=0` here to be certain that cron doesn't think that the script failed; if you have a non-zero `status=`, then cron will assume the script failed and take some action. This might be just to email you an error message, which (in this one case) seems unnecessary and *noise*.

---

In fact, if you want to be a little lazy, you can use this to add it to cron ***daily***. The function only selects the first weekday from the 5-7 day-of-month. Code and frame only for demonstration of the days this function returns `TRUE` for: checking every day of 2021, it will only run for these:

```r
vec <- seq(as.Date("2021-01-01"), by = "day", length.out=365)
out <- data.frame(vec, downum = format(vec, format="%a"), dowltr = format(vec, format="%u"),
                  exec = sapply(vec, weekday_run))
out[out$exec,]
#            vec downum dowltr exec
# 5   2021-01-05    Tue      2 TRUE
# 36  2021-02-05    Fri      5 TRUE
# 64  2021-03-05    Fri      5 TRUE
# 95  2021-04-05    Mon      1 TRUE
# 125 2021-05-05    Wed      3 TRUE
# 158 2021-06-07    Mon      1 TRUE
# 186 2021-07-05    Mon      1 TRUE
# 217 2021-08-05    Thu      4 TRUE
# 249 2021-09-06    Mon      1 TRUE
# 278 2021-10-05    Tue      2 TRUE
# 309 2021-11-05    Fri      5 TRUE
# 340 2021-12-06    Mon      1 TRUE
```

Comment: Wow, thank you-the lazy workaround is a perfect solution. I used a condition to check if today's date since the launch date is the first 5, 6 or 7th weekday of each month using lubridate. Thanks again!